# .Match() A or B or C

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a list of spans with a variety of classes. I want to check if a given span has the same class as another element.

```
if ( $(this).attr('class') === getClass.match('Rock, Paper, Scissors') ) {
    //do stuff
}
```

.match doesn't work with a comma separated list. I was wondering how I would do this then.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just

```
$(this).is('.Rock, .Paper, .Scissors')
```

Comment: It needs to return the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Using a pipe separated regex should work.

/A|B|C/

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

Here is the documentation for the test method which will return true/false directly.

```
 var str="Hello world!";
 //look for "Hello" or "world"
 var patt=/Hello|world/g;
 var result=patt.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the `filter` method (http://api.jquery.com/filter/) because your element could have more than one classes in which case the code you've posted might not produce expected result.  You could use the `filter` function as follows:

```
$(this).filter('.Rock, .Paper, .Scissors')
```

So you could use it like follows:

```
$.each($(element).filter('.Rock, .Paper, .Scissors'), function(index, value) {
    // do stuff
});
```